# How can I create a log for an existing daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, daemon

I have a deamon running (that I did not create) and I need to be able to read its logs. Unfortunately, it does not have a log file. Is there a way to pipe the daemon's output into a file, and have it continuously update so I can run tail -f on it?

Comment: Are you sure it's producing output? A daemon doesn't usually write to standard output, so there wouldn't be anything to pipe.

Comment: If it does produce output, use `daemon > filename.log`

Comment: Although - when I do `daemon > filename`, I immediately get output to my terminal, but when I open the file, nothing is there. Should this be happening, or...?

Comment: It may be writing to stderr, so you should also redirect that `daemon > filename 2>&1`.

Comment: That works, but will this cause output to be continuously written ie so I can run a tail -f on it?

Comment: It should be, since stderr is not usually buffered. The problem with this whole thing is rotating log files, since there's no way to tell the daemon to close the file and open a new one, other than by restarting the daemon.

Comment: Does not seem to write continuously - piped daemon into a file, called tail -f, ran an event, and go no update. Re-piped and tailed and saw new output corresponding to the event

Comment: Standard output is normally buffered, standard error is not. That sounds like the message was sent to standard output. You could use the `unbuffer` utility that comes with `Expect` to help with this.

Comment: Check `/proc/fd` you might find an open file handle.

Answer (score 0):

The files under `/proc/<PID>/fd/<FD>` are symlinks to the their corresponding file objects. So, if a program with PID 45920 is reading from a file at `/home/hypnotoad/all_glory_to_the_hypnotoad`, and that file is mapped to file descriptor `3`, then running `ls -l /proc/45920/fd/3` will yield:

```
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Mar 15 18:33 /proc/45920/fd/3 -> /home/hypnotoad/all_glory_to_the_hypnotoad
```

So, if you have the PID of the daemon process, you can see what file descriptors it has open (and what files those descriptors map to) using `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd/` and you can find out a bit more about those descriptors using `find /proc/<PID>/fdinfo/ | xargs -n 1 cat`.

Of course, it'll have file descriptors `0` (stdin), `1` (stdout), and `2` (stderr) open, and it may have file descriptor `255` open (for a tty). If fdinfo indicates a `pos` value other than zero, that means the file descriptor is almost certainly in use (because it gives the position of the pointer into the file / stream / what-have-you).

If it really isn't logging to any files on-disk, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process#1323999) on redirecting output from a running process may be of use to you. Worth noting that it's possible to have `gdb` execute commands from a file, rather than interactively, so that you can minimize daemon interruption time.

Also worth noting in passing that the process you use to run `gdb` will be subject to the usual restrictions surrounding the [`ptrace` syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), so you'll want to make sure your process is either running as root, or running in some other context such that it can attach to the daemon.

Alternatively, of course, if you don't mind having the daemon down for a little while, you could run it inside a docker container and capture the output that way.